# Hidden vector recovery problem?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

A certain problem has shown up in my research recently that feels like it could be a preexisting problem in convex geometry, but I am not familiar with the area.
I'll describe the problem (and a *partial* solution to it), but I'm more interested in whether this problem is known in the literature than whether this partial solution can be improved --- I'm sure it can, and will spend some time thinking about this myself.

The problem is as follows.
I have a "hidden" vector $\vec v\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ I wish to recover, and two (public) convex bodies $K_0 \subseteq K_1$, where

1. $\vec v \in K_1\setminus K_0$
2. $K_1$ is the fundamental domain of some lattice $L$ (i.e. $L +K_1 = \mathbb{R}^n$ is a partition, and for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ it is contained in a translate $\ell + K_1$ of $K_1$ by $\ell\in L$).

In both cases (for me) $K_i$ are scaled hypercubes, but this doesn't seem fundamental.

Anyway, one is given an oracle that, on input a linear transformation $T$

1. returns $\bot$ if $T(K_0)$ is not contained in $K_1$, and
2. otherwise returns the unique lattice point $\ell$ such that $T(\vec v)\in \ell + K_1$, i.e. returns $T(\vec v)$ "rounded" to the nearest lattice point of $L$.

It seems like one should be able to adaptively choose some sequence of linear transformations to recover $\vec v$.
In the simplest case (which is still interesting for me) of $K_i$ scaled unit cubes, one can do a "binary search along each coordinate" to recover some good approximation to $\vec v$ (the smaller $K_0$ is, the better approximation it is).
This is already quite useful for me.
It seems plausible that by using $T$ that are rotations as well one can get better results though, perhaps exactly recovering $\vec v$ in the case of $K_i$ scaled unit cubes.

Anyway, it wouldn't surprise me at all if this were a known problem in convex geometry, so I'm asking if anyone has heard of it (or a similar problem), as connecting a problem in my research to a preexisting problem in another field is always an interesting proposition.

Comment: "Exact recovering" seems impossible for a vector with real coordinates. For such a vector we can take a close vector, producing exactly same oracle's responses for any (finite) query series.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Good point. In practice $\vec v$ can be assumed to be in $\mathbb{Z}^n$, which may enable exact recovery. One could also include further assumptions on the $K_i$ (say that they are the convex hull of finitely many rational vertices), but I'll avoid this for now.

Comment: if K_0 is the octahedron inscribed in the cube K_1, then it feels you might need a lot of queries if n is large